# In-App Update ask for purchase it again

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am selling apps via In-App within my App, currently what I am doing is, when anyone has already purchased the In-App item, then at the time of update it ask for purchase it again, it doesn't charge any money but it asks each time for log in and password, Is any way to skip this log in progress, I want it should be updated without asking for purchase and log in password.

Comment: You mean once user makes purchases, the UI state should persist? The UI should always show up based on user has purchased or not?

Comment: No, That I am able to track I am able to get whether User has purchased it or not, but I do want to skip the process of asking "Do you want to purchase this app?"

Comment: Once you start payment, all the alerts are delivered from the Store Kit Framework. There is no way we could control them. If it's non consumable products, you can check if user has already purchased product. If not, allow purchase and up on successful payment, save in user defaults or key chain so that next time we know the product was successfully purchased.

Comment: So if I use Auto-Renewable Subscriptions or Consumable then?

Comment: Consumable means every time user purchases he will need to make payment. Non Consumable means payment is done only once (per iTunes account), after that, lets say if user deletes the app and tries to purchase again with same iTunes account then it will only be downloaded. No money will be deducted. Subscription means payment once made is valid for some period of time. After the period expires, then user needs to make payment again.

Comment: Ok thank you, Then what I can only do is give a message to user that "No money will be deducted".

Comment: Even if you don't give and user tries to purchase an already purchased  non-consumable product with the same iTunes account, he will automatically get the message in the alert that he has already purchased it. Since user may not know about this, it's your duty to show that the product was already purchased. User may get annoyed that he made payment once and is again asked to purchase.

Comment: Your UI should simply show user "Purchase" when it's not yet purchased. Once it's purchased, it should always show "purchased".

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to cache the user's purchase history on disk somehow in order to prevent this from happening, otherwise you'll have to ask the user to authenticate with Apple at least once (through running a transaction restore or by re-purchasing your products).